# How to check what files a process has written into

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, process

I have an Excel application that stores some information somewhere in my computer, and I need to know where that file is located. This Excel file is some kind of Visual-Studio-created Excel application, not VBA coded. I can't have the source.

So, I need to know how to find out which files a process has written into, or which files it has created. How can I get this information?

I use Windows 7 and MS Office 2007.

Answer (score 6):

Open Windows' built-in `Resource Monitor`, switch to `Disk` tab, put a checkmark next to your process and the `Disk Activity` section below you'll see all the files that process accessed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) - It has the ability to show which files are open/written to etc. and is the best equivalent of 'lsof' which is a Linux tool, for Windows

Comment: How?. Because I can see the files being used but not their relationship with processes. How do you see what files are owned by a process?. Or what process is using a file?.  I couldn't find it on Process Explorer nor Process Hacker

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Process Monitor` to track this.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645

Launch Process Monitor and then your application.

Process Monitor will log every file and registry access made.

You will probably need to filter out the noise of other applications running.